# How is this integral $ \int_a^b \frac{(x-c)^2}{x(1-x)} dx $ evaluated?

Tags: calculus

Given $a, b, c \in (0,1)$, how shall the integral
$$
\int_a^b  \frac{(x-c)^2}{x(1-x)} dx
$$
be evaluated? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you tried?

Comment: Try partial fractions.

Comment: @copper.hat: Thanks! Can you be more specific?

Comment: No. Look it up.

Comment: @rlgordonma: I am reading a paper and try to verify the statement.

Comment: And what statement are you trying to evaluate in the paper?

Comment: @copper.hat: p768 of www.hep.caltech.edu/~fcp/statistics/hypothesisTest/PoissonConsistency/AndersonDarling1954.pdf

Comment: I get a 404 on that.

Comment: @copper.hat: Not sure why.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing it is expanding the integrand in partial fractions:
$$
\frac{x^2-2cx+c^2}{x(1-x)}=\frac{c^2}{x}-\frac{(c-1)^2}{x-1}-1
$$
so you get three simple integral instead of one. Can you handle from here?

Answer (score 1):

$c^2 \cdot ln(x) - (c-1)^2 \cdot ln(1-x) -x ~|_a^b$

Comment: The question is "How shall the integral be evaluated" not "what is the integral", at homework there shouldn't be solutions, and for the result they could use wolfram alpha anyway

Comment: If you want to know, where this function came from, deriviate it and get the function under the integral.

Comment: please tell me you aren't serious, this only veryfies it is right, without learning anything.

Comment: Seriosly? By deriviating you get ${c^2 \over x} + {(c-1)^2 \over {1-x}} -1$. So everything you must to do is to put default function in this form and solve easy integral. That is a full way. Not just an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
Multiply it out and use partial fraction decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int_a^b  \frac{(x-c)^2(x+(1-x))}{x(1-x)} dx=\int_a^b  \frac{(x-c)^2}{x} dx+
\int_a^b  \frac{((x-1)-(c-1))^2}{(x-1)} dx
$$

Now, expand each power and it's easy then

Answer (score 1):

Please bear in mind the integral you're asking does not converge for a=0 & b=1. But it does for any open interval of the form (0,1).

The problem is, once you do the primitive, you get a log(1-x) and a log(x). Please remember lim x->0 log(x) = -inf.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's stated as part of the problem that a cannot be 0 and b cannot be 1 so that was a rather unnecessary statement.